# Changing the source of image tag in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an `<img>` tag that represents the *album cover* of songs. I can fetch the song's album cover picture using [`music-metadata`](https://github.com/Borewit/music-metadata) parser, like this:

```
const mm = require('music-metadata')
mm.parseFile(music_filepath)
    .then(metadata => {
        console.log(metadata)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message)
    })
```

Now if I look at the console, I have something like this:

[image: metadata]

So I can fetch the picture using `metadata['common']['picture'][0]['data']`.

The HTML for the image tag is this (which uses a default picture for album cover):

```
<img id="album-cover" src="assets/images/Album Cover.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
```

I'm aware that I can change this picture using pure JavaScript, like this:

```
let album_cover = document.getElementById('album-cover')
album_cover.src = new_picture_path
```

But this method uses `file path`. How can I change the picture directly from `metadata`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a base64 of your image and pass it to the attribute of your image by doing something like this  :

```
const request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
const mm = require('music-metadata')

const generateBase64 = url  => {
    return new Promise(
        resolve => {
          request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              const  data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer.from(body).toString('base64')
              return (resolve(data))
          }
          return(resolve(null))
        }
      )}
    )
  }

mm.parseFile(music_filepath)
    .then(async metadata => {
        const base64 = await generateBase64(metadata)
        if (!base64) return;
        const album_cover = document.getElementById('album-cover')
        album_cover.setAttribute('src', base64);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set base64 ed img

document.getElementById('imgTest')
    .setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAU//8/==');

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [answer provided by aperesso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57235663/6282576), I solved it like this.

```
let acf = metadata['common']['picture'][0]['format'] // album_cover_format
let acd = metadata['common']['picture'][0]['data'] // album_cover_data
album_cover.src = `data:${acf};base64,${Buffer.from(acd).toString('base64')}`
```